# How to insert custom markup in a drupal 7 main-menu?

Tags: routes

In order to justify my menu items following what reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536/how-do-i-really-justify-a-horizontal-menu-in-htmlcss), I have to achieve a menu-structure like the following one.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

This means that I have to insert an empty `<span></span>` at the end of `<ul>`.

How can this be done? Can I do it in the template.php file?

Comment: It can be done using CSS... You don't need to change the menu structure to style it.. Get a CSS expert advice or post in stackoverflow posting drupal default menu structure and ask what you are looking for using the default structure.

Comment: Thanks @anil-sager, i've found a pure CSS-Solution on the site i already mentioned in my question: there is one answer which uses the pseudo-content ul:after{content:""}